# Error : getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443

Tags: angularjs, node.js, windows, npm, npm-install

I am working on a corporate network.

Trying to install `npm.` But I'm getting this error again and again.

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program     Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org    registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Angular-test\angular-phonecat\npm-debug.log
```

Tried this also: `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Still getting the same error.

Comment: Does your system connected to internet?

Comment: As the error message states, you face a problem connecting to `registry.npmjs.org`. Follow the state advice and properly configure network access on your computer.

Comment: @abdulbarik -- yes. System is connected to the internet

Comment: @HolgerJust - configure network access? have proper internet access. Do you mean any proxy issues?

Comment: Even tried git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://

Comment: This helped me resolve this issue --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/45877279/20414576

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this command

```
npm config delete proxy
```

It happens because `formidable` is prone to severity vulnerability. So, you need to override that by running the above command.

Comment: Hi! according to the comment on abdulbarik's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39593195/1008011), the asker has already tried what you have suggested and it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 51):

Things to try:

1. make sure you have internet connection: `ping 8.8.8.8`
2. make sure you have DNS resolver working: `ping www.google.com`
3. make sure you can access registry.npmjs.org: `ping registry.npmjs.org`
4. make sure you can connect via https.

Try in your browser: https://registry.npmjs.org/

Make sure you are trying to connect to:

- `registry.npmjs.org`

and not to:

- `"registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443"`

or some other weird string composed of few hostnames, because it's weird that the resolver complains about a hostnames that includes a port number, which it shouldn't care about. Ok, I tested and it should look like this for hosts that are not found.

### Update

From your comment to this answer it seems that you are **not** directly connected to the internet if you can't even ping 8.8.8.8.

If you are using a proxy to access the Web, then you also have to configure `npm` to use it. Use:

```
npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://example.com:8080
```

but instead of `http://example.com:8080` use what you actually need in your company - ask someone or see how your browser is configured.

To see your proxy configuration in Chrome, see [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96815?hl=en).

### Update 2

If you **can** access https://registry.npmjs.org/ in your browser but you **cannot** run `ping registry.npmjs.org` then it means that your browser must be configured to use a proxy, or other programs than your browser must be restricted from using the internet.

In any case, you should ask someone in your company about it because most likely you either need to use a specific proxy or someone needs to lift the restriction from your `npm` and allow it to access the network.

The network access can be blocked by a firewall installed on your computer or a router in your network. It's hard to say without knowing the specific configuration in your company.

### Update 3

Remove the environment variable "https_proxy" if any or use correct value for "https_proxy"

Comment: 1.Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8 Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss), 2.Ping request could not find host www.google.com. Please check the name and try again. 3. same as 2nd 4. getting some data

Comment: network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNR. This is most likely not a problem with npm itself. Network and is related to network connectivity.In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network setting.If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Comment: Got the above error, even after trying the command you mentioned @rsp

Comment: @BhuvanaK But did you substitute the `example.com` with your actual company proxy? Did you find it in your browser's settings or asked someone in your company about what the server and port should be? See Update 2 to my answer.

Comment: Yes Now working fine. Mismatch happen. In proxy, entered port as 8080. In npm, tried with 8000. Now it's working fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: @BhuvanaK That's good to hear. You can accept the answer so others can see that the problem is solved. Here is [how to accept the answer properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: If you're connecting to "registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443" try running this "npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/" found the answer here >> https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9630

Answer (score 22):

use: https://registry.npmjs.org/
Make sure you are trying to connect to:

> **[registry.npmjs.org](http://registry.npmjs.org)**

if there is no error,try to clear cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then try

```
npm install
```

even you have any error

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

then try

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`  was the key. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

I tried many but this worked fine for me.

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

above 2 commands is enough if it doesn't work try this as well.

```
npm config --global rm proxy
npm config --global rm https-proxy
```

Comment: The `--gloabl` was the important part... pretty nasty... Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 10):

First, edit NetworkManager.conf file:

```
vim /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Comment this line:

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

Finally

```
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: tankyou @jansanchez it help me alot

Comment: THIS. Had the exact same issue @bhuvana-k mentioned while being connected directly  to the internet. Connecting through the web browser would work while pulling dependencies via `npm` would fail - disabling `dnsmasq` helped - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are working behind proxy you must set proxy for npm to connect it to repo.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set proxy http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.somecompany.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.somecompany.com:8080
npm config set strict-ssl false
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.somecompany.com:8080
set HTTP_PROXY=http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.somecompany.com:8080
```

**Note** If your password **contains special character** like **@**  EX:  password : mypwd1@xyz
then use  %40 in place of @   Ex:

```
npm config set proxy http://myusername:mypwd1%40xyz@proxy.somecompany.com:8080
```

Comment: For me It worl like --- I set npm config set proxy http://proxy.ops.xxx-yyy.zzz:8080/ and npm config set https_proxy http://proxy.ops.xxx-yyy.zzz:8080/ . here " http://proxy.ops.xxx-yyy.zzz:8080/" will be your company provided proxy and it work like a charm

Answer (score 2):

```sh
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

this is the only solution for me.

Comment: Is it possible to briefly explain what part of the actual question is missing because it is wrong, why the operation command was able to solve the problem, and what the actual result is?

Answer (score 1):

In my case very alike error (`ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org`) was fixed by adding `--no-bin-links` to npm install command.

Wierd but might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

If Ubuntu try opening 
All Settings > Network > Network proxy
set the method to automatic and save.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The reason was the corporate proxy issue. 
Solution was to set the proxy setting as @rsp says.

```
npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://example.com:8080
```

But later I face the same issue. This time reason was my password contains a special character.

> In this command you can’t provide a password with special character

. So solution is to provide percentage encoded special character in the password.

> For example # has to provide as %23

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 0):

I spent over 5 hours trying to get rid of this message under Windows 8.1. So I would like to share my case and save someones time. I was not behind the proxy... but setting proxy helped to resolve the problem. So I go deep and found that issue was caused by Comodo Firewall... which blocked cmd since I was installing packages too fast (turning off and even closing Firewall did not help, which caused me so long to find the issue... seems like there was some other process of Firewall running in background). You may have same issue with any other firewall/antivirus installed so make sure that cmd is not blocked by them. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was just an **intermittent** issues it seems, didn't work for a few tries, then looked at https://registry.npmjs.org (webpage worked fine), tried again, tried again and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Subsystem Linux:

Restarting my WSL terminal (bash/shell) fixed the issue (it took a few restarts and minutes, however).

use nslookup www.google.com
or npm.org to check connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use this command

> **npm config set registry https://registry.your-registry.npme.io/**

This we are doing to set our companies Enterprise registry as our default registry.

You can try other given solutions also.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this issue occurs if you are using the system provided by your organization and you are connected to its vpn.
In this case, disconnect from the vpn and then try executing this command.

Answer (score 0):

npm config rm proxy

npm config rm https-proxy

npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

These 3 commands one after the other worked for me.

Comment: It's better to prepent CLI commands with some introductory words. The commands themselves are better formatted as code blocks

Answer (score 0):

Running `sudo service docker restart` was the key for me! Prior to running this command, I was able to access the `npm` registry using ping and the browser.

Answer (score 0):

use this command it will work
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

Comment: your answer has english grammar errors, and does not explain clearly how to fix the issue.
Please, when you answer a question, take your time into creating an answer that can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was with DNS not able to resolve IP against a particular domain. Pointing to 8.8.8.8 google DNS resolved the issue.