# having trouble in installing angular in my windos os

Tags: angular, npm

```
C:\Users\ZOYA ZEE>npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ZOYA ZEE\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-20T12_09_19_129Z-debug.log

C:\Users\ZOYA ZEE>npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: Dou you have problems with your internet connection?

Comment: Did you just install Node.JS? If so, then it's necessary to restart your computer.

Comment: yes i have installed node js and also npm

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 idea:

1. Try to run npm install -g @angular/cli
2. In case you will have error: did you run it from power shell or command line?
   Cause I had a problem with "ng new app" from power shell, but in a command-line it was correct

Answer (score 0):

Dou you have problems with your internet connection?

From your error, which says

> ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org

It seems as though internet connection is low, or restricted.

Try looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592908/error-getaddrinfo-enotfound-registry-npmjs-org-registry-npmjs-org443?fireglass_rsn=true) answer to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, of all check, your internet connection is working or not. And if there is no problem with the internet then use below command

$ npm cache verify

$ npm cache clean --force

and then try again.

If you still get the error then use the yarn package manager. Install yarn by running this

$  npm install -g yarn

and then configure angular cli to use the yarn package manager, by running this command

$ ng config -g cli.packageManager yarn