# how to get rid of from the this error while installing the angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I m consistently facing this issues every time when I try to install the angular at my Office PC
I did google everything about this fatal but I failed

Here is the log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   '@angular/cli'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.15.1
4 verbose npm-session 626545a01678ba14
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/cli@latest request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 11333ms
10 verbose type system
11 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
11 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
11 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
11 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:469:9)
11 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
11 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
11 verbose stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
11 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
12 verbose cwd C:\Users\H S COMPUTER S HYD
13 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
14 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
15 verbose node v14.15.1
16 verbose npm  v6.14.8
17 error code ENOTFOUND
18 error errno ENOTFOUND
19 error network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
20 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
20 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
20 error network
20 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
20 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
21 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Here is the Image
[image]

Any help would be appreciated & thanks in Advance

Comment: It seems your system is unable to fetch data from npm; have you tried this [might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592908/error-getaddrinfo-enotfound-registry-npmjs-org-registry-npmjs-org443)

Comment: Like the error message says: Seems like a network problem. Your computer is not able to resolve `registry.npmjs.org` to a valid IP address. Can you acess in the browser? Can you `ping registry.npmjs.org` in the console?